# Count Array DISTINCT above 1

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, cakephp

How can i count only if customer_id exist more than 1.

Because i only wanna count if number exist more than 1 time.

```
 $customerOrder = $this->Order->find('all', array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Order.customer_id >' => '0',
                    'Order.status' => 'Delivered'
                )
            ));
 $b = array_unique($customerOrder);
Echo Count(array_unique(array_diff_key($customerOrder, $b)));
```

As minimum i should get 3: 
it should give result about 100. This is a little screenshot of list: [image]

Comment: do you want it on PHP or Mysql ?

Comment: If you are selecting `DISTINCT Order.contomer_id` you will only see one of each customer_id even if there are 1000 all with an id or `1`

Comment: Thanks for your answers. @AlwaysSunny I want it on php?

RiggsFolly Yes i know, but if i dont use DISTINCT then it will count  all customer_id, even if same customer_id exist more than 5 etc. 

i thougt maybe something like DISTINCT (2) but not sure how to do

Comment: Group by customer id, filter via count in the having clause. **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12157380/how-to-count-duplicate-values-in-cakephp/12157585**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this method? Array unique, array diff key and count.

```
$a = array(1,2,3,3,3,4,1,1,3,2);
$b = array_unique($a);


Echo Count(array_unique(array_diff_key($a, $b)));
```

https://3v4l.org/La1mN

Comment: $customerOrder = $this->Order->find('count', array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Order.customer_id >' => '0',
                    'Order.status' => 'Delivered'
                )
            ));

$b = array_unique($customerOrder);


Echo Count(array_unique(array_diff_key($customerOrder, $b)));

i get 0. i am sure its more than 0 result ?

Comment: @MTal Don't know. What is in  $customerOrder? Can you make an 3v4l on it?

Comment: i have now uploaded a screenshot hope it helps :)

Comment: @MTal do a `var_dump($customerOrder);` and copy paste the output. There must be something with the array values them self

Comment: I get only Array. 
but it doesnt do anything

Comment: @MTal So var_dump returns the word Array. Nothing else? I really need the copy paste to help you.

Comment: @MTal can I see the var dump?

Comment: Yes correct i only receive the word Array and nothing else. 

Sorry did not get what you need from me, before you can help?

Comment: Where should i place the var_dump($customerOrder);

Comment: @MTal anywhere after you get the values from database. If it returns empty then either you misspelled a variable or your database connection is not working. The code I provided works as you can see from the Links. It's your code that does not work.

Comment: Yes your code working fine have tried with array.

My connection works fine to database maybe something in this code is wrong? `$customerOrderTwo = $this->Order->find('count', array(
               'conditions' => array(
                   'Order.customer_id >' => '0',
                   'Order.status'       => 'Delivered'
               ) 
            ));`

Comment: @MTal don't know what the problem is. But I can't test it, and therefore I can't help you with it. But the question you had, finding two or more in array is solved by all answers here I believe. You should accept the answer you find best and if you need help with the $customerOrder you should open a new question.

Comment: No problem Thank you very much for support :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `array_count_values`

```
function greaterNum($var)
{
    return($var>=2);
}

$array = array(1,2,3,3,3,4,1);
$counts = array_count_values($array);
print_r(array_filter($counts,"greaterNum"));
```

It will return

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [3] => 3
)
```

The key represents the value of original array and value represents the number of times it occurred in original array.

```
 print(count(array_filter(array_count_values($array),"greaterNum")));
```

It will print `2`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way with [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to find which value appears how many times? , see the result of **$result** for clear understanding and then use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop or [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter) or any other way to get only values with occurrence greater than **2** times.

```
<?php
$values = array(1,2,3,3,3,4,1,8,0,0,9,8);
$result = array_count_values($values);

//debugging
print '<pre>';
print_r($result);
print '</pre>';

$count = 0;
foreach($result as $count_value){
    if($count_value >= 2){
       $count++;
    }
}

echo $count;
?>
```